# Strange kernel segmentation fault in Integrate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, crash

**Bug introduced in 8.0 or earlier and fixed in 11.0**

---

Define

```
tointegrate = D[V[y1[t], y2[t]], y2[t]] D[V[y1[t], y2[t]], {y1[t], 2}]
```

and try to find its indefinite integral

```
Integrate[tointegrate, t]
```

MathKernel crashes with no messages after a few second. Other simple indefinite integral problems do yield fine non-coredumping results.

Tested with Mathematica Version

- "10.2.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (July 28, 2015)"
- "8.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (October 10, 2011)"

Do you observe the same behaviour in other versions? Any idea of why gets Mathematica going up the spout on this?

Best,

Comment: Confirmed in 8.0.4 and 9.0.1 on Windows.

Comment: Confirmed in 10.0.2 and 8.0.1 on OSX 10.10.5.

Comment: Wolfram technical support confirms this is a bug, and should be working on it.

Answer (score 2):

On v11, on mac os:

```
In[4]:= tointegrate = D[V[y1[t], y2[t]], y2[t]] D[V[y1[t], y2[t]], {y1[t], 2}]
Out[4]= Derivative[0, 1][V][y1[t], y2[t]]*Derivative[2, 0][V][y1[t], y2[t]]

In[5]:= Integrate[tointegrate, t]
Out[5]=
 Integrate[Derivative[0, 1][V][y1[t], y2[t]]*Derivative[2, 0][V][y1[t], y2[t]], t]
```